# Magento Move billing address below shipping address in checkout

Tags: checkout

I want to move the billing address form below the shipping address in the checkout, on the first page/step.

I created a custom module like tigren method https://www.tigren.com/billing-under-shipping-address-m2/

It all works fine, but when I press the place order button and want to complete the order I get the following error message:

"please check the billing address information. regionid is required."

So the billing address is not transferred, who can help me?

Comment: editing the checkout on a way like this is very complicated in M2. Its hard to tell without having the code, so if you have the possibility to show it to us, this would be great to find what is going wrong...
 
When debugging the error i would first take a look on the api requests to find out what is going wrong when saving the billing-address. it needs either to be a shipping-information or billing-address call to the magento api.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your billing address doesn't have required `State/Province` filled, and somehow, validation on first shipping step omit address validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below extension given here in my blog:

https://marketplace.magento.com/ananta-module-improvedcheckout.html

Tested and worked with 2.4.5

[image]
[image]